# Receiving empty file when downloaded

Tags: php

I'm trying to download files form server using PHP by passing the path and file name through URL, like this:

```
<a class="downloadBtn" style="float:left;" href="download_file.php?folder=<?php echo $codrepresentante.'&file='.$nomeArquivo ?>" >download</a>
```

Then I receive this PHP file:

```
<?php

$fileName = $_GET['file'];
$coisa=urldecode($fileName);

$path= "http://localhost/portal/boletos/".$_GET["folder"];
$filePath = $path.'/'.$coisa;
echo "caminho: ".$filePath;

if(file_exists($filePath)){
    // Define headers

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$coisa);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($coisa));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    // Read the file
    echo readfile($filePath);
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'The file does not exist.';
}
?>
```

But I always get empty files or the `The file does not exist` response.

I got the `$filePath` variable  and used in the browser to see if the path was wrong, but it worked, so the path is correct.

Could someone help me by indicating where I made a mistake?

Comment: Is it a local file? If so `$path= "./".$_GET["folder"];` but be aware your code is vulnerable to someone simply supplying paths and downloading your files.

Comment: the path is correct, i think, because as i mentioned in the question if i get the $filepath from the echo and use it in the browser  the file appears,and thanks for the advice.

Comment: I dont think it is `file_exists('http://localhost/portal/boletos/folder/file.ext')` wont work as expected. Because a http call is not a file, directory or unc path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Receiving empty file

Based on the code you've shown us, there shouldn't be any download at all.

> echo "caminho: ".$filePath;

You're not seeing the errors PHP is reporting to you.

> filesize($coisa)

That's the filename - not its full path.

> but i always get empty files or the 'The file does not exist.'

So you don't get any download, zero length or other.

> got the $filePath variable and used in the browser to see if the path was wrong

In the browser you specify a path relative to the document root - but in your PHP code your paths should be relative to the filesystem root.

You need to start by

- learning how to describe an issue accurately
- making sure you are capturing the error and warning messages PHP is telling you about
- add instrumentation to your code so you can capture the internal state as the execution progresses
- breakdown the coponent parts of what you are trying to achieve and test them in isolation

Comment: first thanks for the advices, about the paths i tried calling the directory above and going to another using "../boletos/$_GET["folder]" but it still didnt work.

Comment: i found the problem, it was the name of the file that had ".pdf" in its name so it ended like file.pdf.pdf, so it wasnt finding it.